# monomac - how to call a new form when click a button

Tags: monomac

My Monomac project has 2 forms (Form/Views): `Mainwindow` and `form2`. (I created `form2` using: New -> monomac -> Cocoa View with controller > name is : form2)

On the `MainWindow` form I have a button. I want to make `form2` show/visible when I click that button.

Action when button is clicked is: `a1`. This is my code :

```
partial void a1 (NSObject sender) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine ("a1 call form2");
    var f1 = new form2Controller();
    f1.LoadView();

}
```

I want to show `form2` once the view is loaded, what must I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a "Cocoa **Window** with controller", then you want to do this to show the window:

```
f1.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront();
```

If you've created a "Cocoa **View** with controller", then you have to hook up your window that you added to the xib to an outlet, then call it like:

```
f1.MyOutletForTheWindow.MakeKeyAndOrderFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a window visible, you will need to call the ShowWindow method of the view controller.

```
partial void a1 (NSObject sender)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("a1 call form2");
    Form2Controller form = new Form2Controller();
    form.ShowWindow(this);
}
```